# Wrong reference to equation: Reference to section instead of equation number

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, boxes

I try to reference in the text to an equation number like:

```
see equation \ref{eqdesign2}
```

the equation is:

```
\sbox{\myendhook}{%
\begin{footnotesize}%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
        $\mu_m$ & Magnetic permeability [$H/m$]\\
        $N$     & Number of windings [-]\\
        $A$     & Area of the coil [$m^2$]\\
        $l$     & Length of the coil [$m$]
    \end{tabular}
\end{footnotesize}
}
\begin{fleqns}[2em]
    \begin{equation}
        L_1 = \frac{\mu_m N^2 A}{l}
        \label{eqdesign2}
    \end{equation}
\end{fleqns}
```

Such that the outcome is

[image: Wrong reference]

As you can see the reference to the equation is not correct. I tried solving this by using 'gather', such that the code becomes:

```
see equation \ref{eqdesign3}

\sbox{\myendhook}{%
\begin{footnotesize}%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
        $\mu_m$ & Magnetic permeability [$H/m$]\\
        $N$     & Number of windings [-]\\
        $A$     & Area of the coil [$m^2$]\\
        $l$     & Length of the coil [$m$]
    \end{tabular}
\end{footnotesize}
}
\begin{fleqns}[2em]
    \begin{gather}
        L_1 = \frac{\mu_m N^2 A}{l}
        \label{eqdesign3}
    \end{gather}
\end{fleqns}
```

The reference is now good, but the \sbox with table is not displayed anymore.

[image: Does not show box]

The box is made with the following code:

```
\makeatletter
\@fleqntrue
\let\old@mathmargin=\@mathmargin
\@mathmargin=-1sp
\let\oldmathindent=\mathindent
\let\mathindent=\@mathmargin
\newsavebox{\myendhook} % for the tabulars
\def\tagform@#1{{(\maketag@@@{\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}
  \makebox[0pt][r]{% after the equation number
    \makebox[0.4\textwidth][l]{\usebox{\myendhook}}}%
  \global\sbox{\myendhook}{}% empty box
}}
\makeatother
```

Someone an idea on how to solve the reference or solving the box display?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide the compilable document that has this issue, not only fragments. At the moment it looks like if the `\@currentlabel` content is stuck inside the box you're defining and never get's out.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that you like to have something like this:

[image]

Since you not provide MWE, I haven't clue  for what you need new environment. Above image of equation is obtain by fairly simpler code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
see equation \ref{eqdesign3}

    \begin{flalign}\label{eqdesign3}
L_1 & = \frac{\mu_m N^2 A}{l}
    &   &   \begin{tabular}{>{\footnotesize $}r<{$:}>{\footnotesize}l}
         \mu_m  & Magnetic permeability [$H/m$]\\
            N   & Number of windings [-]\\
            A   & Area of the coil [$m^2$]\\
            l   & Length of the coil [$m$]
            \end{tabular}
    \end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

*Note:* the `footnotesize` is not an environment, sou your use is wrong.